# how to move canvas using drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html

--html--

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>


<body>
  <div id="title">
    <h2>Sliding Puzzle</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    <form>
      <label>Easy</label>
      <input type="range" id="scale" value="4" min="3" max="5" step="1">
      <label>Hard</label>
    </form>
    <br>
  </div>


  <div id="main" class="main">
    <canvas id="puzzle" width="480px" height="480px"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script src="sliding.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---JavaScript

```
var context = document.getElementById('puzzle').getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'img1.jpg';
img.addEventListener('load', drawTiles, false);

var boardSize = document.getElementById('puzzle').width;
var tileCount = document.getElementById('scale').value;

var tileSize = boardSize / tileCount;

var clickLoc = new Object;
clickLoc.x = 0;
clickLoc.y = 0;

var emptyLoc = new Object;
emptyLoc.x = 0;
emptyLoc.y = 0;

var solved = false;

var boardParts = new Object;
setBoard();

document.getElementById('scale').onchange = function() {
  tileCount = this.value;
  tileSize = boardSize / tileCount;
  setBoard();
  drawTiles();
};

document.getElementById('puzzle').onmousemove = function(e) {
  clickLoc.x = Math.floor((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / tileSize);
  clickLoc.y = Math.floor((e.pageY - this.offsetTop) / tileSize);
};

document.getElementById('puzzle').onclick = function() {
  if (distance(clickLoc.x, clickLoc.y, emptyLoc.x, emptyLoc.y) == 1) {
    slideTile(emptyLoc, clickLoc);
    drawTiles();
  }
  if (solved) {
    setTimeout(function() {alert("You solved it!");}, 500);
  }
};

function setBoard() {
  boardParts = new Array(tileCount);
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    boardParts[i] = new Array(tileCount);
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      boardParts[i][j] = new Object;
      boardParts[i][j].x = (tileCount - 1) - i;
      boardParts[i][j].y = (tileCount - 1) - j;
    }
  }
  emptyLoc.x = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].x;
  emptyLoc.y = boardParts[tileCount - 1][tileCount - 1].y;
  solved = false;
}

function drawTiles() {
  context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , boardSize , boardSize );
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      var x = boardParts[i][j].x;
      var y = boardParts[i][j].y;
      if(i != emptyLoc.x || j != emptyLoc.y || solved == true) {
        context.drawImage(img, x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize,
            i * tileSize, j * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
      }
    }
  }
}

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return Math.abs(x1 - x2) + Math.abs(y1 - y2);
}

function slideTile(toLoc, fromLoc) {
  if (!solved) {
    boardParts[toLoc.x][toLoc.y].x = boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].x;
    boardParts[toLoc.x][toLoc.y].y = boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].y;
    boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].x = tileCount - 1;
    boardParts[fromLoc.x][fromLoc.y].y = tileCount - 1;
    toLoc.x = fromLoc.x;
    toLoc.y = fromLoc.y;
    checkSolved();
  }
}

function checkSolved() {
  var flag = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tileCount; ++j) {
      if (boardParts[i][j].x != i || boardParts[i][j].y != j) {
        flag = false;
      }
    }
  }
  solved = flag;
}
```

this works properly but i wont to move puzzle items using drag and drop(http://html5.brucealderman.info/sliding.html).in this example works on click event. (onmousemove,onclick) how can i rewrite these functions to work drags and drop.(JavaScript and html only)

Comment: Can't you use jquery? Seriously to do drag/drop in pure javascript is waste of time if there is a supported and well-tested library to do this. Check http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: no,i can't use jquary.js only. if u know how to do it using js.please help me.